# LWJGL and openGL - giving tiles ID's

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have this question, i want to give each tile a seprate ID, but I don't know how and there doesn't seem to be any post about it either. So what i want to have is that I can edit each tile independently, without all tiles doing the same things. If you know the answer, please say what I can edit, thanks in advance.

-bryan

Code: (everything draws on the screen perfectly BTW)

```
public static void drawQuadTex(Texture tex, float x, float y, float quadWidth, float quadHeight){
    tex.bind();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);


    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(quadWidth, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(quadWidth, quadHeight);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, quadHeight);

    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();

}
```

so how can I apply an ID to this?

Comment: You get the same tile every time because you draw the same tile every time... But: you don't need a unique ID, you already *have* one! The x and y coordinates are unique for each and every tile; a simple 2D array is enough.

Comment: actually, i have diffrent textures because i have another class for it, but thanks for reminding me of the X and Y :)

Comment: actually, I have a double array list where I can fetch from :)